# How to "Create environment variable file with: touch .env for configuration (in project root)."

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

basically just don't understand what this line means, did everything else already https://github.com/adityasarvaiya/Automatic_Question_Generation#environment-variables

Comment: You linked to a page with hundreds of lines. Could you please cut and paste the specific line directly into your question?

Comment: The information is inadequate? Next time, please summarize your problem.

Answer (score 5):

`touch` is a shell command for Unix-like operating systems.

If you have a Unix/Linux/MacOs terminal you navigate to the project root directory and type `touch .env` which will create a file named `.env` to hold configuration information.

In that same terminal you can type `man touch` for more information, or read the [manual online](https://linux.die.net/man/1/touch)

Comment: what about on windows?

Comment: Looks like `@COPY /B %1+,, %1` should work.
See the superuser answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the terminal
2. touch .env
   your file is created. All you need is to go to your location and click on show hidden file

There you can see your env file